# Poison on Xenomorphs -- was it ever attempted?

Tags: alien-franchise, biology

In the scene where Ripley gets a lot of support for her idea of nuking the aliens from space, the first suggestion is to use nerve gas. (Which is not really embraced by anyone -- nuking is "the only way to be sure".)

Is this some indication that the marines are still thinking of the operation as a "bug hunt"? (Nerve gas-like agents are indeed used as insecticides -- first they were used or created for warfare and then after ww2 (in which they were not used) it was discovered that such agents also worked in insects which is why you should be at least very careful of insecticde usage or find an alternative.)

Has any method of killing xenomorphs been discovered that does not involve heat (or cold) or  mechanical force been discovered? It is not clear that xenomorphs need to breathe (or eat) so perhaps nerve gas would be extremely ineffective for two reasons: one, they would not need to inhale any agent (we saw them swim underwater for long periods) and two, any creature so physically different than those we have previously encountered might not have a nervous system remotely like those of humans (or "bugs"). On the other hand, their biology might have some overlap with that of the host species.

NOTE: One might think in Resurrection that the two xenos kill the third using acid but what it seems like to me that the xeno just batter it to break open its body to release enough acid to make a hole in the cell; the acid does not seem to be dangerous to the xenos themselves as makes sense since their bodies hold it.

The freezing gas is apparently unpleasant to the xenos which implies that perhaps enough cold for an extended period might damage/kill them but the only one killed by the intense cold is a human, showing the understanding btw that xenos (maybe particularly clones from a human) have of human technology.

Comment: I think a xenomorph got poured with molten lead in the 3rd movie, which by itself didn't seem to affect it (although lead poisoning isn't an instant death either).

Comment: Just speculation here, but the facehugger in ALIEN was able to easily adapt to the *Nostromo's* terrestrial environment (Ash says something about it generating a layer of polarized silicon or something) which was very different from the toxic (to us) atmosphere of LV-426. This suggests an inherent resistance/ability to adapt to chemical threats.   It's not impossible that resistance could extend to the Xenomorph spawned from a host as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, bear with me, as I read this book 30 years ago and my memory is hazy.
I think in the aliens novel "Nightmare asylum" by Steve Perry, there was a fungus or something that killed or at least hurt an alien hive.
General Spears, the villain of the story was once held prisoner in a hive when he was a teen, but survived by cultivating and spreading a fungus that had already infected a hive. When the aliens were too weak to hold him, and he just walked out. The military subsequently destroyed the hive and the fungus, despite him telling them how valuable it could be. The wiki entry doesn't mention the fungus, but in story it was only mentioned as part of a flashback when general Spears was describing why he was so interested in the aliens.  It wasn't particularly important to the plot.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens%3A_Nightmare_Asylum?wprov=sfla1

Comment: That must be a heck of a fungus because I assume the immune system of a xeno must be very powerful -- how does a spore survive in such an acidic environment as the blood of the xeno? I assume this was addressed in the story.

Comment: I don't think they addressed it.  Part of the point of General Spears telling the story was that it was tragic that they never found out more about it.  Personally, I think it could have been a disease from the Alien homeworld, that evolved to infect the Aliens.  Keep in mind, this was long before Prometheus retconned the Alien origins.

Comment: It is worth saying that Spears is a VERY unreliable narrator and he can be simply lying.

Comment: @Yasskier: Unreliable narration is annoying and I wonder why such characters are included.

Comment: @releseabe well, in that particular case to show how unhinged Spears was maybe? His story suggests that xenomorphs are far more intelligent than suspected: that they know basic medicine (a fungal "soup" protecting from plague), that they keep slaves (Spears was free to wander the hive) and even try to "grow more humans" (in the story they immobilised Spears mother and then forced him to rape her).